# How can I receive input through notifications in bash?

Tags: shell, gnome, notifications

When I get a chat message in Empathy, I get a notification in GNOME Shell. This notification allows me to input a reply directly, instead of having to switch to Empathy.

Is there any way I can get a similar prompt from a shell script?

Comment: just for your information, your question got very close to being closed as "unclear what you're asking". I (think I) understood what you meant, so I edited your question, but in the future, please try to be much more specific.

Comment: Thank you strugee. It was my first question on this site. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. At least not without using a GNOME Shell extension.

Here's why. GNOME, along with other desktops, uses a desktop standard from the FreeDesktop (non-)standards body. This particular standard is called Telepathy.

Essentially, Telepathy provides an abstract way of dealing with chat for desktop sessions like GNOME. So in Telepathy, a Telepathy client (like Empathy) doesn't have to care about what protocol it's talking to underneath. It just talks to Telepathy, and then Telepathy will forward on that request to some daemon that is *actually* responsible for speaking whatever protocol you're using. These daemons are called Telepathy providers. This all gets tied together through the magic of D-Bus.

Empathy is a Telepathy client that is a traditional "app". However, Telepathy clients don't have to be "apps" with windows and menubars and buttons and everything. They can also be, oh, I don't know... a component of a notifications system.

Yep, the input that you are seeing is actually the notifications subsystem of GNOME Shell being a Telepathy consumer. The notification isn't tied to Empathy at all: it originates from Telepathy, not Empathy.

That means that the "input notification" isn't a general framework for input in notifications. It doesn't work for arbitrary things. It *only* works for Telepathy, and so we arrive at the sad answer to your question... there is no way to ask for input like this from a shell script.

Perhaps look into `zenity(1)`?

Comment: But why can't he just register his script with dbus and do the same thing?

Comment: @mikeserv uh, because it's not designed for that? you'd run into all sorts of weirdness. e.g. the prompt appearing in Empathy too. and what are you suggesting the script register as? a Telepathy provider?

Comment: Yeah - why not? Well, as a dbus provider anyway. I don't know much about either - but your answer seems to indicate it's possible. A quick google turns [this up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021975/2955202). A comment there links to [this github mirror](https://gist.github.com/vi/2307606).

Comment: @mikeserv I mean, maybe... it'd be bloody stupid. it's just not designed for that and I don't see why OP can't just use Zenity.

Comment: there's also `dbus-send` which is the shell interface that comes with `dbus` - but I haven't got a clue how it works. Anyway, you've probably got it.

Comment: @AbhayMittal my pleasure. good luck!